# Shrink 2D Vector into smaller 2D Vector

Tags: c++

I have a large 2D vector of size NxM

```
vector<vector<int> > grid;
```

I need to shrink it by dividing it by a fixed number 
eg. 
N = 194 M = 231 need to shrink by 7 (Round up)
Which means the new grid needs to be of size N= 28 M= 33.

The original grid has 0's and 1's, so i need to break down the array into 7x7 blocks and if all the values == 0 then the cell in the new grid is = 0, But if at least one of the values are 1, then the value in the new cell must be 1.

I wrote a few functions but cannot seem to get it. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried something like this which i found and was trying to adapt

```
for (int i=0; i < rows - k_rows + 1; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j < cols -k_cols + 1; j++)
   {
       int sum = 0;
       for (int p=i; p< k_rows +i; p++)
           for (int q=j; q < k_cols + j; q++)
               sum += mat[p][q];
       file << sum;
   }
   file << endl;
```

Comment: Please, post at least one of the functions you've tried so far.

Comment: Off topic: you don't have a 2D vector. You have a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I believe user45891 is right that there is a common image processing problem that looks like this. But, this is a very inaccurate version of it.  So I'm not going to go into that. I did write a full example program (~80 lines).

Here are some ideas:
  create a new matrix of the size you want it to be, and initialize it to false (I used booleans since you only wanted 0s and 1s ).
  Iterate through this new (smaller) matrix and set each value to the return of a function that searches a subset of the original matrix for 1s.

-> You'll pass this function the x1,x2->y1,y2 range you want to search of the original matrix

-> calculate that range using the shrink factor

this new function did_i_find_a_one(x,x2,y,y2)  just returns whether or not there is a 1 in that block or not.

In addition to the following code, I wrote functions to display the matrix so I could visualize the result. But I think this was the meat of it.  I do think there may be better ways of doing it if you had really large maps. But naively, this can't be that bad.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef vector<bool> boolvector;
typedef vector<boolvector> matrix;

void initialize( matrix &i, uint newx, uint newy ) {
  i.resize(newy);
  for( auto it = i.begin(); it != i.end(); ++it) {
    it->resize(newx,0);
  }
}

void shrink( matrix &orig, matrix &to, uint factor=10 ) {
  uint _y=orig.size();
  uint _x=orig[0].size();
  uint newy=(_y + factor - 1)/factor; //round up division
  uint newx=(_x + factor - 1)/factor;
  initialize(to, newx, newy)

  for (uint y=0; y<newy; ++y) { 
    for (uint x=0; x<newx; ++x) {
      to[y][x]=is_one_in_block(x*factor,(x+1)*factor-1,y*factor,(y+1)*factor-1);
    }
  }
}

bool is_one_in_block( matrix & _i, uint x1, uint x2, uint y1, uint y2) {
  uint _y=_i.size();
  uint _x=_i[0].size();
  if (y2>_y-1) y2=_y-1; //over max protection
  if (x2>_x-1) x2=_x-1; //over max protection
  for (uint y=y1; y<=y2; ++y)
    for (uint x=x1; x<=x2; ++x)
      if (_i[y][x])
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: That sounds great! I am learning ROS and I have my world map which is huge and I want to shrink my matrix by the size of the robot so that each cell is the size of the robot.
I have spent hours on this small problem. If you have the code that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds very similar to using filters in image processing. In that context you would let a [convolution matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) (in Crop mode) slide over an image.

The Wiki article has sample code, I will outline the general steps here:

1. Iterate through the 2d vector in the x and y dimension. But don't start at index 0 - start at `shrinkFactor/2` and iterate up to `.size() - shrinkFactor/2`.
2. Gather the convolution matrix / block. It is probably easiest to create a new 1d array and run two loops. The outer one from `x - shrinkFactor/2` to `x + shrinkFactor/2` and vice versa for y.

   3. Test whether that array is all zeroes and populate your output accordingly